# hdd issue in my ubuntu as well as in windows 8 too

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

i have a 1TB external hdd but its showing some error in ubuntu

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/ubuntu/NAPSTER: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/ubuntu/NAPSTER"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.

Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted

The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/378694/unable-to-mount-internel-hard-drive

I hope it will help you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First you have to boot again to windows and shutdown the computer regularly

Then you ca mount the harddisk with command:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/ubuntu/NAPSTER
```